# Unable to calculate CPU usage % properly

Tags: shell, digital-ocean, cpu-usage, droplet

I am using the script provided [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/calculating-cpu-usage-from-the-monitoring-api) with a small difference as quoted below to fetch the CPU usage of a droplet VM.

snd date as current time in seconds
start date as current time - 180 seconds

But still I am not able to fetch the utilization properly. Screenshot of shell script output and CPU utilization graph is provided.

[image]
[image]

Any idea why am I not getting the actual utilization as per the graph?

Update 1:

```
#!/bin/bash


TOKEN="myToken"
HOST_ID="myId"

while true
do
# Get the current time in seconds since the epoch
end_time=$(date +%s)

echo "Current time: $end_time"

# Calculate 5 minutes before the current time
start_time=($(date +%s) - 180)

API_ENDPOINT="https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/monitoring/metrics/droplet/cpu?host_id=$HOST_ID&start=$start_time&end=$end_time"

# Get the metrics
RESPONSE=$(curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" "$API_ENDPOINT")

# Parse the metrics
IDLE=$(echo "$RESPONSE" | jq -r '[.data.result[] | select(.metric.mode == "idle") | .values[0][1]] | add')
TOTAL=$(echo "$RESPONSE" | jq -r '[.data.result[] | .values[0][1] | tonumber] | add')

echo "IDLE: $IDLE"
echo "TOTAL: $TOTAL"

USED=$(echo "$TOTAL - $IDLE" | bc)

echo "USED: $USED"

ZERO_CHECK=$(echo "$TOTAL == 0" | bc)
if [ $ZERO_CHECK -eq 1 ]; then
 echo "No change in TOTAL, can't calculate CPU Usage"
else
 CPU_USAGE=$(echo "scale=2; ($USED / $TOTAL) * 100" | bc)
 echo "CPU Usage: $CPU_USAGE%"
 fi
done
```

[image]

Comment: Please [don't post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: Regarding "# Calculate 5 minutes before the current time" followed by `start_time=($(date +%s) - 180)` - 180 seconds is 3 minutes, not 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I notice in the shell script output that your "Current time" output is increasing by about 30 seconds per iteration - there's no "sleep" or anything else in your script that'd take that kind of time so that means each call to `curl` is taking about 30 seconds to complete which is a very long time - are you sure it's not timing out and populating `RESPONSE` with something other than what you expect?

As you can see in your output, the IDLE and TOTAL values are very similar so if those values are wrong then it's either a problem with your `curl` command or with how you're using `jq` to parse the curl output. You didn't show us an example of `$RESPONSE` so we can't tell if there's an issue in that and I'm not very familiar with `jq` but I notice you have:

```
IDLE=$(  '[ ... | .values[0][1]] | add' )
TOTAL=$( '[ ... | .values[0][1]  | tonumber] | add' )
```

i.e. you call `tonumber` in one case but not the other, I don't know for sure if that's a problem or not but it looks to me like you either need `tonumber` in both places or in neither of them.

Also, by using `CPU_USAGE=$(echo "scale=2; ($USED / $TOTAL) * 100" | bc)` with a small value of USED and large value of TOTAL the result of USED / TOTAL is 0 to 2 decimal places before you multiply it by 100 and still get zero. You'd get a more accurate result with `(USED * 100) / TOTAL`.

I fixed that issue and generally tidied up your script below, try it and post a new question if it still doesn't do what you want but this time only post text, no images, and print the contents of `$response` and `$start_time` as well as everything else you're currently printing..

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

token='myToken'
host_id='myId'

while true
do
    # Get the current time in seconds since the epoch
    end_time=$(date +%s)

    printf 'Current time: %s\n' "$end_time"

    # Calculate 5 minutes before the current time
    start_time=$(( end_time - 180 ))  # <- actually 3 minutes

    printf -v api_endpoint 'https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/monitoring/metrics/droplet/cpu?host_id=%s&start=%s&end=%s' "$host_id" "$start_time" "$end_time"

    # Get the metrics
    response=$(curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" "$api_endpoint")

    # Parse the metrics
    idle=$( printf '%s\n' "$response" | jq -r '[.data.result[] | select(.metric.mode == "idle") | .values[0][1]] | add')
    total=$(printf '%s\n' "$response" | jq -r '[.data.result[] | .values[0][1] | tonumber] | add')

    printf 'idle: %s\n' "$idle"
    printf 'total: %s\n' "$total"

    used=$(printf '%s - %s\n' "$total" "$idle" | bc)

    printf 'used: %s\n' "$used"

    zero_check=$(printf '%s == 0\n' "$total" | bc)
    if (( zero_check == 1 )); then
        printf "No change in total, can't calculate CPU Usage\n"
    else
        cpu_usage=$(printf 'scale=2; (%s * 100) / %s\n' "$used" "$total" | bc)
        printf 'CPU Usage: %s\n' "$cpu_usage"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Hi Ed, I have just tried to execute your script as is (modified token and host id), however I see errors in output this time. I have created a new question based on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77685729/unable-to-get-cpu-usage-over-api

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested this with the following modification:

```
API_ENDPOINT="https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/monitoring/metrics/droplet/cpu?host_id=$HOST_ID&start=$(($(date +%s) - 180))&end=$(date +%s)"
```

> Note the `($(date +%s) - 180)` in the `start` time.

And it seems to be working as expected.

What is the exact change that you made in the script?

Comment: Updated the question with the script I am using and screenshot.
However, if I keep both start time and end time as same $(date +%s), I get cpu usage as 1% when the utilization graph shows 100%.